# Change color of http:// links in bash

Tags: bash, shell, colors, echo

I would like to know if you can modify bash to change the color of certain types of links, like UNC or http:// directly when 'echo-ing' the output no matter the command i'm running (using debian, bash)

i've built a shell in C before, it was easy to:  if find 'thing*', echo (stuff for color code) + value + rest of the line

how do i do that in bash ?

Answer (score 2):

Bash doesn't colour the output of commands; it's a function of your terminal application.